# ReadFile in Base64 Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, base64, readfile

I'm trying to read an image from client side encoded in base64.
How to read with nodejs?

My code:

```
// add to buffer base64 image
var encondedImage = new Buffer(image.name, 'base64');

fs.readFile(encondedImage, "base64", function(err, buffer){
    if ( err ) {
        console.log('In read file')
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        // check err
        lwip.open(buffer, 'jpg', function(err, image){
            console.log('in open')
            if ( err ) console.log(err)

            if ( image ) console.log(image)
            // check 'err'. use 'image'.
            // image.resize(...), etc.
        });
    }
})
```

But, I got this error:

```
In read file
[Error: Path must be a string without null bytes.]
```

Comment: `fs.readFile` takes a string as its first argument. You're trying to pass it a `Buffer`.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Latest and greatest way to do this:

Node supports file and buffer operations with the [`base64` encoding](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const contents = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/file.jpg', {encoding: 'base64'});
```

Or using the new [promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options):

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const contents = await fs.readFile('/path/to/file.jpg', {encoding: 'base64'});
```

Comment: `fs.readFileSync('/path/to/file.jpg', {encoding: 'base64'})` does not decode the binary... it's equivalent to `fs.readFileSync('/path/to/file.jpg', 'utf8')` we're merely passing an encoding argument to get a string instead of a buffer

Answer (score 135):

I think that the following example demonstrates what you need:
I removed the link because it was broken.

The essence of the article is this code part:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// function to encode file data to base64 encoded string
function base64_encode(file) {
    // read binary data
    var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
    // convert binary data to base64 encoded string
    return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
}

// function to create file from base64 encoded string
function base64_decode(base64str, file) {
    // create buffer object from base64 encoded string, it is important to tell the constructor that the string is base64 encoded
    var bitmap = new Buffer(base64str, 'base64');
    // write buffer to file
    fs.writeFileSync(file, bitmap);
    console.log('******** File created from base64 encoded string ********');
}

// convert image to base64 encoded string
var base64str = base64_encode('kitten.jpg');
console.log(base64str);
// convert base64 string back to image 
base64_decode(base64str, 'copy.jpg');
```

Comment: I got buffer is undefined error. I am missing some js library or something else

Comment: @Krishnavrinsoft: You need to have node.js installed. https://nodejs.org

Comment: If the goal is to create a base64-encoded [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) the solution falls a bit short. The actual data is correct, but the string is missing the `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],` prefix.

Comment: You are right I think, but that was not part of the question for as far as I have understood it.

Comment: `new Buffer` is redundant. `fs.readFileSync` returns buffer if encoding is not specified. You can just do `fs.readFileSync([..]).toString('BASE64')`.

Comment: @Gajus You can even go farther. readFileSync now can do the encoding for you. Just do `fs.readFileSync('...', { encoding: 'BASE64' })`

Comment: the link seems broken!

Comment: It helps A LOT! `function base64_encode(file) {
    var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
    return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
}` Thank you!

Comment: downvoting for converting buffer to buffer `new Buffer()` can be removed

Answer (score 10):

```
var fs = require('fs');

function base64Encode(file) {
    var body = fs.readFileSync(file);
    return body.toString('base64');
}


var base64String = base64Encode('test.jpg');
console.log(base64String);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code reads a text file. Then converts it to text, then reads it as base64 and puts that into a binary buffer, and saves it back to a true  binary.

```
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs'
import { tmpdir } from 'os'
const contents = readFileSync('./temp.txt')
const buffedInput = Buffer.from(contents.toString(), 'base64')
writeFileSync(`${tmpdir}/temp.zip`, buffedInput)
```